# Problema ao carregar font-awesome com o SASS

Tags: css3, sass, font-awesome

Os ícones ao serem carregados estão bem diferentes.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> CAMERA
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> FACEBOOK
<i class="fa fa-github"></i> GITHUB
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou carregando o `font-awesome` da seguinte maneira :

tenho um diretório `sass/tools/_vendor.sass`:

```
// Bootstrap-Sass
@import ../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap

// Font-Awesome
@import ../../bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome

// Font Open-Sans
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300)

// Breakpoint-Sass
@import ../../bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint

// Sass Flex Mixin
@import ../../bower_components/sass-flex-mixin/flex
```

e um `sass/main.sass` que minifico:

```
@import settings/variables

@import tools/mixins
@import tools/vendors

@import generic/reset

@import components/header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troquei em :

> bower_components/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss

```
    $fa-font-path:        "../fonts" !default;
```

para :

```
    $fa-font-path:        "/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts" !default;
```